# How with Python Tkinter do I fix the size irrelevant of text of buttons?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

I have the following example code:

```
    # Button grid modifications
    self.connectButton.grid(row=5, columnspan=2,
        sticky=N + S + E + W)
    self.SelectButton.grid(row=6, rowspan=2, column=0,
        sticky=N + S + E + W)
    self.configButton.grid(row=6, rowspan=2, column=1,
        sticky=N + S + E + W)
    self.ImageButton.grid(row=7, columnspan=2,
        sticky=N + S + E + W)
    self.ImageButton2.grid(row=8, columnspan=2,
        sticky=N + S + E + W)
```

This displays a 2 column button over two 1 column buttons over a few more 2 column buttons.  Depending on the text I use, it changes drastically and unproportionally both vertically and horizontally. I've tried using the weight=1 but that didn't seem to work either.  I know there has to be a simple solution.  How can I get it to be the same regardless of text / platform?  This is supposed to be portable.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`config`**](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm) with specific `width` to keep your buttons fixed:

```
self.connectButton.config(width=some_width_as_int)
```

Comment: So I've found that using config width on at least one tkinter object per column works, but if the text exceeds that width it still stretches the button.  Do I just have to be careful about the text I have on my buttons versus width?  I was hoping for just an easy way that built a fixed grid and I can say rowspan/columnspan and it just autofills.  I have the sticky=N+W+S+E

Comment: don't use sticky for fixed widgets, sticky will always stretch your widget using all available area between widgets

Comment: i don't know how your app look like, but i would create a frame, put all my buttons in that frame using pack instead of grid and add width using config so buttons will be with fixed size